# Get 10 random elements in Django template

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make a quiz in Django, and I need to get ten random elements from the class Question in a template. This ten elements will be then used in a for loop inside that same template to show on screen the ten random questions to the user.

Any ideas on how to select a certain number of random objects in a Django template?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do random in a template instead of in the view function?

Comment: Probably because I didn't know that option. How would it work?

Comment: return the list of 10 random elements to the template -- are you using template, view and django ORM?

Comment: Yes, that is correct